# Fixed header make dropdown navbar not work

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a `navbar`. When I hover it, a dropdown menu will appear. But when I put a style for fixed header on my `navbar`, the dropdown does not display the menu until the bottom. It looks like it's cut off.

```css
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-item">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="nav-menu mobile-menu ">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Item1</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>
              <a class="font-weight-bold">List Item </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="font-weight-bold">List Item </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="font-weight-bold">List Item </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="font-weight-bold">List Item </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="font-weight-bold">List Item </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="font-weight-bold">List Item </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="font-weight-bold">List Item </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="font-weight-bold">List Item </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="font-weight-bold">List Item </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="font-weight-bold">List Item </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="font-weight-bold">This is not Last Item </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="font-weight-bold">This is Last List Item </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item2</a>
          <ul class="dropdown"></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

and this is my screenshot for my navbar :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CDP1.png)

Thank you

Comment: could you attach full html file and css for it?

Comment: @TomaszBucko this is my code https://jsfiddle.net/b6dzsrve/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this style to your `.dropdown`:

```
height: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Comment: Is that a question, a comment or an answer?